# Kotlin extension function start activity with Intent extras

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

I am trying to write a kotlin extension function for Context which will start a new activity in android with given class name and list of intent extras. I am able to successfully start activity without any extras but I am facing problem with them.

```
fun <T> Context.openActivity(it: Class<T>, pairs: List<Pair<String, Any>>) {
  var intent = Intent()
  pairs.forEach {
     intent.putExtra(it.first, it.second)
  }
  startActivity(intent)
}
```

> Main issue here is -> intent.putExtra() doesn't except second param as
>   Any

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of using a list of pairs, consider using a `Bundle`. Then you can add it with [`putExtras(Bundle)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras(android.os.Bundle)).

If you want to go one step ahead, you could add a lambda extension to configure the extras:

```
fun <T> Context.openActivity(it: Class<T>, extras: Bundle.() -> Unit = {}) {
  val intent = Intent(this, it)
  intent.putExtras(Bundle().apply(extras))
  startActivity(intent)
}
```

Then you can call it as:

```
openActivity(MyActivity::class.java) {
  putString("string.key", "string.value")
  putInt("string.key", 43)
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this brilliant lambda extension approach. Can you please redirect me to a site where I can read more about this as a want to understand the concept of this extension approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: intent.addExtras(Bundle().apply(extras)) 
1)This doesn't exist 2) If I want to add flag in intent how?

Comment: @Subho 1 was a spelling issue. The text was more exact about it. For 2 you'd have to implement `openActivity` to also set the flag to the intent or use a closure with `Intent` as a receiver instead.

Comment: Are you referring to my answer? @tynn

Answer (score 18):

**Declare:**

```
inline fun <reified T : Activity> Context.startActivity(block: Intent.() -> Unit = {}) {
    startActivity(Intent(this, T::class.java).apply(block))
}
```

**Simple using:**

```
startActivity<MainActivity>()
```

**With extra**

```
startActivity<MainActivity>{
   putExtra("param 1", "Simple")
}
```

Comment: additionally, instead of `block(intent)` you can also call `intent.block()` or `Intent(this, T::class.java).apply(block)`

Comment: @SubaruTashiro Can you please show entire code for what you suggest? It seems nicer.

Comment: inline fun <reified T : Activity> Context.startActivity(block: Intent.() -> Unit = {}) {
    startActivity(Intent(this, T::class.java).apply(block))
}

Comment: Thanks to Subaru Tashiro, Crypher. I just edited my answer.

Comment: Amazing way of writing an ext class

Answer (score 3):

Here is the extension function for start activity:

```
inline fun <reified T : Activity> Context.openActivity(vararg params: Pair<String, Any>) {
    val intent = Intent(this, T::class.java)
    intent.putExtras(*params)
    this.startActivity(intent)
}

fun Intent.putExtras(vararg params: Pair<String, Any>): Intent {
    if (params.isEmpty()) return this
    params.forEach { (key, value) ->
        when (value) {
            is Int -> putExtra(key, value)
            is Byte -> putExtra(key, value)
            is Char -> putExtra(key, value)
            is Long -> putExtra(key, value)
            is Float -> putExtra(key, value)
            is Short -> putExtra(key, value)
            is Double -> putExtra(key, value)
            is Boolean -> putExtra(key, value)
            is Bundle -> putExtra(key, value)
            is String -> putExtra(key, value)
            is IntArray -> putExtra(key, value)
            is ByteArray -> putExtra(key, value)
            is CharArray -> putExtra(key, value)
            is LongArray -> putExtra(key, value)
            is FloatArray -> putExtra(key, value)
            is Parcelable -> putExtra(key, value)
            is ShortArray -> putExtra(key, value)
            is DoubleArray -> putExtra(key, value)
            is BooleanArray -> putExtra(key, value)
            is CharSequence -> putExtra(key, value)
            is Array<*> -> {
                when {
                    value.isArrayOf<String>() ->
                        putExtra(key, value as Array<String?>)
                    value.isArrayOf<Parcelable>() ->
                        putExtra(key, value as Array<Parcelable?>)
                    value.isArrayOf<CharSequence>() ->
                        putExtra(key, value as Array<CharSequence?>)
                    else -> putExtra(key, value)
                }
            }
            is Serializable -> putExtra(key, value)
        }
    }
    return this
}
```

Simple using:

```
openActivity<TestActivity>("key0" to "value0", "key1" to "value1")
```

A simpler approach is provided in Kotlin

> Use the bundleOf()

```
inline fun <reified T : Activity> Context.openActivity1(vararg params: Pair<String, Any?>) {
    val intent = Intent(this, T::class.java)
    intent.putExtras(bundleOf(*params))
    this.startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: Hi you can use bundleOf() in Kotlin for passing params in android Kotlin

Comment: @NafisKabbo I just discovered this method. It's very convenient. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here is the extension function for start activity:

```
inline fun <reified T : Activity> Context.openActivity(noinline extra: Intent.() -> Unit) {
      val intent = Intent(this, T::class.java)
      intent.extra()
      startActivity(intent)
}
```

You can call this function like this way:

```
openActivity<MyActivity> {
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    putExtra(LaBoxConstants.DEFAULT_LANDING, Default_Landing)
    putExtra(HomeActivity.APP_RELAUNCH, AppReLaunched)
}
```

**NOTE: IT IS NOT A RECOMMENDED WAY TO START ACTIVITY. USE STARTACTIVITY INSTEAD.**

Comment: why is this not a recommended way to start activity? it seems pretty convenient to me

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer an approach where I have a method that defines the flag for an activity, to prevent having to re-write the flags for every startActivity invocation.

```
internal inline fun <reified T: Activity> Context.startActivity(activity: KClass<T>, noinline modifyIntent: Intent.() -> Unit) {
    val intent = Intent(this, activity.java)
        .addFlags(flagsForActivity(activity))
        .modifyIntent()

    startActivity(intent)
}

private fun <T: Activity> flagsForActivity(activity: KClass<T>): Int {
    return when (activity) {
        LoginActivity::class -> Intent.SPECIFIC_FLAGS
        else -> Intent.DEFAULT_FLAGS
    }
}
```

And then the way it would be called is

```
startActivity(LoginActivity::class) {
    putExtra("Username", "username")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no method `putExtra(String, Any)` in the `Intent` object. You can use `Bundle` object to save your data:

```
fun <T> Context.openActivity(it: Class<T>, bundleKey: String, bundle: Bundle) {
    var intent = Intent(this, it)
    intent.putExtra(bundleKey, bundle)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

To call it inside `Context` object:

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString("Key", "Value") // you can put another object here
openActivity(SomeActivity::class.java, "Bundle Key", bundle)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private inline fun <reified T : Any> Context.startActivity() {
    val intent = Intent(this, T::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
}
```

pass activity using

`startActivity<MainActivity2>()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).